# Rails validation message

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form_for with validations. I am not displaying any error message if validation fails. But still the submit button moves down if the validation fails for text_area. How do I prevent it?

```
        <%= form_for :scribble do |f| %>
            <%= f.text_area :scribble, cols: 65, rows: 4,:maxlength => 255%><br />
            <%= f.submit %>
        <% end %>
```

.

```
validates :scribble,length: {minimum: 5, maximum: 255}, presence:true
```

Comment: what do you mean by `button moves down`?

Comment: I'm unsure what you want: do you want the error message to show or do you want it not to show but not have the button move? I suspect that the error message div is being shown though empty, causing the view to blip down a tad.

Comment: @jaydel: Your last statement is what I am asking. So I need to make the height and width of the div zero?

Comment: That would be one way to address it (I think). you could also filter the error you want to ignore out and let the conditional do its normal magic. Please note that my assumption about the div might be incorrect. It's worth looking at though...